# MLA: How to cite academic summaries

Tags: citations, mla, plagiarism

When writing long academic summaries, like 2 or more pages long, how should we acknowledge the sources in MLA format?
Should it be as in the example below?

**Original**

*Buffy, a small, delicate-looking blonde of superhuman strength, relies on Giles not only for adult support and coaching, but also for the research necessary to do that for which the Vampire Slayer has been chosen. In the third season, Giles was officially relieved from his Watcher duties, but he ignores that and continues as Buffy's trainer, confidant, and father-figure.*

**Summary in Paper (MLA)**

*To help her fulfill her Slayer duties, Buffy can always turn to Giles **(DeCandido 44)**.*

The example above illustrates how to cite short summaries, but I’m not sure if this same format should be used to cite longer summaries of more than two pages in length.

By the way, I'm not asking about summaries you can insert into longer papers, such as essays, reviews, etc., as supporting details. I'm asking about summaries in itself as one single assignment, e.g. book summaries, movie summaries, etc. Those kinds of summaries that your teacher would ask you to write for homework.

Also, how do you cite a short or long summary from multiple sources?

Comment: While I don't think this is entirely off topic here, I think you might get better answers faster on http://academia.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

There are citation websites across the internet such as citationmachine.net and easybib.com that do this for you in multiple formats. I would suggest using them, as they make life much, much easier.